# python's matplotlib hexbin: why are some hexbins in a column always shifted or offset slightly?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Im using matplotlib.pyplot.hexbin() but have found something weird in the alignment of the hexagons. 
See picture below which results from the following code:

```
x = np.concatenate([[20]*50, [1,2,3,4,5]])
y = np.concatenate([range(50), [1,2,3,4,5]])

plt.figure(figsize=[10,20])
plt.hexbin(x, y, gridsize=(20,50),cmap=plt.cm.YlOrRd)
plt.axis([-1, 21, -1, 51])
cb = plt.colorbar()
```

[image: Values from about 15-35 shifted to the left of the rest of the column of bins]

Can someone explain to me why this is happening and if it can be fixed so all coordinates with the same x-value are aligned and not shifted like this? It is very important to what I'm plotting.

Comment: I don't have to time to do further checking but apparently `gridspace` does not give you, what you expect. It actually gives you 51 bins with `x` range from 19.6 to 20.4 and thusly they are not properly aligned with your `range(50)`. Eventually, one of your values is not fitting in one of the bins in that column but goes into the column left of it which exactly terminates as 20 in `x` direction. I am not sure why the `gridsize` works that way. If I will find out, I'll post an answer. A hotfix is to choose `gridsize=(20, 49)`.